# Physics in tracked scenes, not working

Tags: camera, physics, rigid-body-simulation, tracking, rigidbody

I've already made plenty of Blender physics simulations in my life but when i try physics in a camera tracked scene, literally nothing happens. Always. All setup is the same as in other scenes but when there's a tracked camera, simulations don't work for me :/

For example, my current problem is :

I simply tracked a camera motion (and in addition also object motion - my hand) and I'm trying to make a cube fall off my hand on the table. But as i mentioned, physics doesn't work. I add a rigid body, passive, active, mesh, animated for hand blablabla but no active objects are falling. I also tried to add a completely new, casual cube, also added rigid body to it and still nothinng happened. I made the object tracking from [Jonathan Kron's YT tutorial](https://youtu.be/2z5FXiv7dt8)

His Cube is falling but mine is not :(

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

After I converted **Constraint to F-curve** it start to simulate.
Why it is not working like in tutorial from 2020 ... hm ... a bug?

[image]